# Kafka messages are being consumed multiple times by different consumers with same group ID

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, messaging

I am using kafka with java sprig.
I can see that messages which are being produced only once, are being consumed multiple time.

Some times the message is being consumed only once and other times the message is being consumed multiple time.
According to my logs the message handling are starting at a very close time with difference of few milliseconds. 
I can see that the message processing is happens multiple time with no errors, and finishes before the 'max.poll.interval.ms'.

Some times the processing is in the same service pod in different threads and some times in different pods.
All the pods have the exact same group Id.
This happens in all of the topics of this group Id.

In addition I keep seeing a lot of the following errors:

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.sendOffsetCommitRequest(ConsumerCoordinator.java:722) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsSync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:600) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1250) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.commitIfNecessary(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1327) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.processCommits(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1188) [spring-kafka-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:688) [spring-kafka-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_202]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_202]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_202]
```

and:

Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member.This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing.You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.

My kafka consumer configurations are:

```
              consumer:
                autoRebalanceEnabled: true
                autoCommitOnError: true
                enableDlq: true
                ackEachRecord: true
                configuration:
                  max.poll.records: 20
                  max.poll.interval.ms: 1000000
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance!!!

Comment: you can find multiple question on the same topic  `Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced`..if you take too much time processing the records you can get this error and the records will be available again after the rebalance

Comment: your poll is taking to much time to process the records \

Comment: In your answer you didn’t take into consideration that I mentioned that the processing of the message are starting at the same time with differences of just a few milliseconds, even before the consumer finished processing the message. What do you suggest about this?